# Possibly not completely understanding exports or jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Just going over some exercises so I can get more proficient at jest and I'm a little confused about something.

Here is the test subject:

```
function createRange(start, end) {
    let range = [];

    for (i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        range.push(i);
    }

    return range;
}

function sumRange(start, end) {
    const range = createRange(start, end);
    let sum = 0;

    range.forEach((el) => (sum += el));

    return sum;
}

module.exports = createRange;
module.exports = sumRange;
```

And this is the test:

```
const sumRange = require('./sumRange');
const createRange = require('./sumRange');

describe('sumRange()', () => {
    it('sums a given range', () => {
        expect(sumRange(1, 3)).toEqual(6);
    });
});

describe('createRange()', () => {
    it('creates a range between given arguments 1-3', () => {
        expect(createRange(1, 3)).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
    });

    it('creates a range between given arguments 7-17', () => {
        expect(createRange(7, 11)).toEqual([7, 8, 9, 10, 11]);
    });
});
```

I first started testing the createRange function and tests were passing. Then moved on to the sumRange function. Once I started testing sumRange the createRange test started failing and were showing the results for sumRange. The results are below:

> FAIL  ./sumRange.spec.js   sumRange()
> ✓ sums a given range (4 ms)   createRange()
> ✕ creates a range between given arguments 1-3 (3 ms)
> ✕ creates a range between given arguments 7-17 (1 ms)
>
> ● createRange() › creates a range between given arguments 1-3
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: [1, 2, 3]
> Received: 6
>
>   10 | describe('createRange()', () => {
>   11 |     it('creates a range between given arguments 1-3', () => {
> > 12 |         expect(createRange(1, 3)).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
>      |                                   ^
>   13 |     });
>   14 | 
>   15 |     it('creates a range between given arguments 7-17', () => {
>
>   at Object.it (ch4_DataStructures/sumRange.spec.js:12:35)
> ```
>
> ● createRange() › creates a range between given arguments 7-17
>
> ```
> expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
>
> Expected: [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
> Received: 45
>
>   14 | 
>   15 |     it('creates a range between given arguments 7-17', () => {
> > 16 |         expect(createRange(7, 11)).toEqual([7, 8, 9, 10, 11]);
>      |                                    ^
>   17 |     });
>   18 | });
>   19 | 
>
>   at Object.it (ch4_DataStructures/sumRange.spec.js:16:36)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total Tests:       2 failed, 1 passed, 3
> total Snapshots:   0 total Time:        0.856 s, estimated 1 s Ran all
> test suites matching /sumRange.spec.js/i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `module.exports` twice, which makes it set to `sumRange` so you are testing `sumRange` in both areas. You could do this instead:

```js
module.exports = { createRange, sumRange };
```

And then import it with:

```js
const { createRange, sumRange } = require("./sumRange");
```